# My answer to this combi problem doesn't match the answer in the book (Problem-Solving Strategies)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, contest-math

[Problems 31 and 32 from Arthur Engel's *Problem-Solving Strategies*.]

Let $n$ children be seated in a line. How many ways can they change their places if they may only move by one place at most? (Answer: the Fibonacci number $F_{n+1}$. Simply consider one of the two kids at the extreme ends. This answer agrees with the one in the book.)

Now repeat the entire thing but with the kids in a circle. How many ways $T_n$ are there for n kids?

First, distinguish some child as, say, Arthur. For $n\ge3$:

- Arthur may choose to stay put, and the rest of the $n-1$ kids can move around in $F_n$ ways, like in the previous one.
- Arthur can exchange places with the kid to his left and the rest can jump around in $F_{n-1}$ ways, or he can swap places with the kid to his right, for $F_{n-1}$ more.
- Every child may move to her right, or to her left, for a total of $2$ ways.

This gives $T_n = F_n + 2F_{n-1} + 2 = F_{n+1} + F_{n-1} + 2$ .

Engel, however, disregards the case where Arthur swaps with the kid to his left and thus gets $T_n = F_n + F_{n-1} + 2= F_{n+1} + 2$ .

Halp.

Comment: Maybe it's Engel who needs help.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You mean there's a mistake in the book? Is my reasoning solid, then?

Comment: Maybe Engel is considering left and right cases equivalent?

Comment: Why not write down all the possibilities for, say, $n=3$ and $n=4$, and see which formula does better?

Comment: Uhm, mine does, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard manual labor gives $T_3 = F_2+F_4+2 = 6$ and $T_4 = F_3+F_5+2 = 9$, so it appears that my formula is correct.